# J Oliver EventStore - Examples exception

Tags: neventstore

when I run EventStore example in doc,it throw exception in SqlPersistenceFactory.cs
 line 39:
Value can not be null
Parameter：dialect

Whether the connection string error in app.config？

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code to show your wireup?  One potential solution is ensuring the providerName value in included in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I add some code in MainPrograms.cs line37--
 .UsingSqlPersistence("EventStore")
   .WidthDialect(new EventStore.Persistence.SqlPersistence.SqlDialects.MsSqlDialect())
   .EnlistIn...